# Which database does Stack Overflow use behind-the-scenes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, technology, database

Stack Overflow is developed using ASP.NET and C#. I found this fact in various answers here. So, I was wondering which database Stack Overflow uses. Is it Microsoft SQL Server, as would be expected with ASP.NET, or some other platform entirely?

Also, what about the membership and authentication? Does it rely on the regular membership classes and tables shipped with the ASP.NET Framework, or they have developed their own user classes, database-tables, etc.?

Comment: Vote to move to meta, however I'm about 95% certain the answer is Sql Server 2008 using Dapper, and I highly highly doubt they use the membership model. Almost all enterprise software step 1 is to replace the membership model.

Comment: This will probably be moved to Meta. Also, don't expect a lot of info to be given out on Membership and Authentication, since that may be a security risk.

Comment: @StuperUser FWIW that's security by obscurity, real security comes with openness. That's very likely why SO open sourced StackID and consumes dotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: @Chris : thanks mate, Actually I was bit lazy about ***reinventing the wheel***, as all programmers point out :P . Now that you told everyone rolls out their own membership model, it indicates that the default is vulnerable to security hazards so I will work on mine too. And **StuperUser**, I don't need to know more info, just wanted to know if they have their own membership model. Once again thank you both

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay I certainly wouldn't say the default membership model is prone to security hazards, or in any way even insecure. The problem with it is that it is just outright designed **AWFUL**. No one wants to use that model to be connected to their system basically. MVC3 tried to fix some of the issues but putting ketchup on a turd sandwich but that doesn't change the fact you're still eating...

Comment: @Chris : LOL, no one could have explained better :P .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the database goes, **SQL Server 2008 R2**.  See [this other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network) for all the gory details on the technology stack used to build SE.  LINQ-to-Sql and [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) are both used for data access concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I think SQL Server: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Interesting_StackOverflow_Database_Queries

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Overflow blog talks some about about their [usage of OpenID](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/).

And the development team has even created their own open source OpenID provider called [StackID](https://code.google.com/p/stackid/).